# "path does not exist" error in py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe, python-2.5

This is my code to create executable for my python script "Chkloc.py" using py2exe.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
from Chkloc import EXE_Revision

setup(name=          'Chkloc',
      version=        EXE_Revision,
      console=       ['Chkloc.py'])
```

I got error "Path does not exist" py2exe generating failed.

Please help.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback?  Hopefully it gave a bit more than that.

Comment: There is a script Chkloc.py.  I need to create an executable for this script. So I tried to create another python file named as Chkloc_py2exe.py which has the code which I have shown above. I have another file called ConvertEXE.bat file which actually converts script to executable. Below is the code that this .bat file has. I run this bat to create Chkloc.exe.

Comment: :: convert Chkloc
python Chkloc_py2exe.py py2exe
if not EXIST dist\Chkloc.exe goto Error

Comment: @Deerparkuser01 Edit your post to include the traceback you put in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are having the same problem I had but try this:

When I tried compiling my code it crashed and I didn't know why so instead of compiling my main code I made a separate short file that only ran the main code.

For sample purposes lets say that we are making a "hello world" program with the main code file called "program.py" and the runner file called "run.py" (to be called "run.exe")

Make the "run.py" file with this content:

```
import program
program.run()
```

And make the "program.py" with this content:

```
def run():
    print "Hello World!"
```

Then just compile the "run.py" file.

NOTE: If you want the code to not be able to be opened by the user then after running the program once delete the ".py" files but leave the ".pyc" equivalents.

Hopes this helps.